# Testdrive not downloading release

Tags: 10.10, usb-drive, live-usb, testdrive

I'm just trying Testdrive.

I have problems downloading maverick release, natty iso download is working.

Could you help?

Comment: Are you seeing any output at all?  Can you also run `testdrive-gtk` from a command line and see if there is any useful output there?  You can paste any relevant output into your question.

Comment: i had no more time yesterday to test, problem seems to be solved this morning, thy for the fast answer, while pressing Sync testdrive downloads the files. Server problems?? :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem seems to be solved this morning, while pressing Sync testdrive downloads the files. Server problems?? :/

Answer (score 5):

As one of the upstreams of TestDrive, I can confirm that the issue was server-side rather than with TestDrive! It is fixed now though.

A bug report was filed against [this issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/testdrive/+bug/710897). I hope this information helps. If there's any further syncing issues or any other one, please don't hesitate to [file bugs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)!

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the ISO file of Ubuntu 10.10?

http://mirror.as29550.net/releases.ubuntu.com//10.10/ubuntu-10.10-desktop-i386.iso